# Upload component (filepond) with image crop/resizing

Tags: reactjs, filepond

I found [filepond](https://github.com/pqina/filepond) upload component. It looks promising but I wondering whether I can use it to crop and resize and image before uploading or its possible only with paid `pintura` editor? The use case is that I want to allow user to upload it's avtar whose size will be 200px x 200px. His file might be of larger size so I want to let him use the part of picture to upload.